# Does the Kubernetes Python client API support multi-thread?

Tags: python, kubernetes

I implement a scheduler with multi-thread to create/delete/binding PODs and monitor them. I often get the following error information, so I want to make sure if the API can be used in this way.

```
2019-11-04 18:00:58,415 WARNING Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] dec
ryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2508)'))': /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/py-mnist-pod-10846?gracePeriodSeconds=20
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac
(_ssl.c:2508)'))': /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/py-mnist-pod-10846?gracePeriodSeconds=20

ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC] sslv3 alert bad record mac (_ssl.c:2508)
```

Environment:

- Kubernetes version (kubectl version): 1.15
- OS: CentOS 7
- Python version :3.7.4
- Python client version :2.0.0 , I must use the version because of the issue 547 (#547)
  https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/547

Comment: Hi, have you figured out the reason and fix for this warning. I am having the same warning in the multi-processing context.

Comment: Hi @kz28, no. I just ignore it because my program still works.